# Scrollbar with static information on windows store application

Tags: c#, scroll, windows-store-apps

I have a Page on my windows store application which will have static information. Basicly it will be used to fill some questions, that is, user will be asked to introduce name, age, etc etc.

The ammount of information is to big, and it doesnt fill on 1 page. I was thinkin on creating something where the usr could scroll down to see the rest of the questions.

Is there any way to do that with static fields? I've tryed with scrollviewer, but no luck.

Comment: This is how the last one shows:
http://i.gyazo.com/9f7db8e498a5417b400502ce91ae7844.png
Cant scroll down and last item shows cutted (It is also cutted on the xaml design)

Comment: Hi there. Was able to solve my problem.

All I had to do is to extend the grid that was inside the scroll viewer to beyond the size of the xaml design, and it allows us to scroll.

Comment: Please note that tags stand alone.  That is, you can't combine multiple tags to create a single concept.  The tags `[windows]`, `[store]` and `[application]` together aren't the same thing as the single `[windows-store-apps]` tag.  Always be sure to read the descriptions that appear when selecting tags!